# Sidestepping for-loops using dplyr 1.0.0

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr, tidyverse

I am just starting to appreciate the power of the new `dplyr 1.0.0`. But after reading the vignettes I need to read some more, and of course there aren't any more so I turn once again to SO.

Say I have the following dataset# using rowwise and c_across to calculate new variables
rm(list = ls())

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(1)
df <- tibble(d_1_a = round(sample(1:10,10,replace=T)),
             d_1_b = round(sample(1:10,10,replace=T)),
             d_1_c = round(sample(1:10,10,replace=T)),
             d_1_d = round(sample(1:10,10,replace=T)),
             d_2_a = round(sample(1:10,10,replace=T)),
             d_2_b = round(sample(1:10,10,replace=T)),
             d_2_c = round(sample(1:10,10,replace=T)),
             d_2_d = round(sample(1:10,10,replace=T)))
```

And I want to calculate row sums for a subset of columns within the dataset and add them to the existing dataset. I came up with the following for-loop

```
for (i in 1:2) {
  namesCols <- grep(paste0("^d_",i,"_[a-z]$"), names(df), perl = T) # indexes of subset of columns
  newDF <- df %>% select(all_of(namesCols)) # extract subset of columns from main
  totDF <- newDF %>% rowwise() %>% 
                     mutate(!!paste0("sum_",i) := sum(c_across(everything()))) %>% # new column from old 
                     select(starts_with("sum")) # now extract just the new column as a dataframe
  df <- cbind(df,totDF) # binds the new column to the old dataframe
}
```

Now if we call the original dataset
df

```
d_1_a d_1_b d_1_c d_1_d d_2_a d_2_b d_2_c d_2_d sum_1 sum_2
1      9     5     5    10     9     2     6     7    29    24
2      4    10     5     6     7     2     8     6    25    23
3      7     6     2     4     8     6     7     1    19    22
4      1    10    10     4     6     6     1     5    25    18
5      2     7     9    10    10     1     4     6    28    21
6      7     9     1     9     7     3     8     1    26    19
7      2     5     4     7     3     3     9     9    18    24
8      3     5     3     6    10     8     9     7    17    34
9      1     9     6     9     6     6     7     7    25    26
10     5     9    10     8     8     7     4     3    32    22
```

We can see the two sum columns, each calculated from a different subset of the existing columns from the original dataset and then added on the end of that dataset.

But I am keen to learn some of the new `dplyr`/`purrr` voodoo but am ignorant of how the syntax works.

**Can anyone suggest a tidyverse version of my for-loop?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Literal translation of the `for` loop would be -

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

bind_cols(df, map_dfc(1:2, function(i) {
  df %>% 
    transmute(!!paste0("sum_",i) := rowSums(
              select(., matches(paste0("^d_",i,"_[a-z]$")))))
}))

#   d_1_a d_1_b d_1_c d_1_d d_2_a d_2_b d_2_c d_2_d sum_1 sum_2
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     9     5     5    10     9     2     6     7    29    24
# 2     4    10     5     6     7     2     8     6    25    23
# 3     7     6     2     4     8     6     7     1    19    22
# 4     1    10    10     4     6     6     1     5    25    18
# 5     2     7     9    10    10     1     4     6    28    21
# 6     7     9     1     9     7     3     8     1    26    19
# 7     2     5     4     7     3     3     9     9    18    24
# 8     3     5     3     6    10     8     9     7    17    34
# 9     1     9     6     9     6     6     7     7    25    26
#10     5     9    10     8     8     7     4     3    32    22
```

---

However, we can also use `split.default`  -

```
bind_cols(df, df %>%
  split.default(sub('.*(\\d+).*', '\\1', names(.))) %>%
  imap_dfc(~.x %>% transmute(!!paste0("sum_",.y) := rowSums(.))))
```

where `sub` part returns the grouping of columns on how to split them.

```
sub('.*(\\d+).*', '\\1', names(df))
#[1] "1" "1" "1" "1" "2" "2" "2" "2"
```